# Angular CLI [npm install -g @angular/cli] getting error SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

On running command npm `install -g @angular/cli`

getting error

```
verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 5285 while parsing near '...uebird-0.7.12-1.tgz"}},"0.7.12-2":{"name...'
353 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
353 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
353 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50
353 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
353 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
354 verbose cwd /Users/<user>/<dir>
355 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
356 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@angular/cli"
357 verbose node v12.18.3
358 verbose npm  v6.14.6
359 error Unexpected token } in JSON at position 5285 while parsing near '...uebird-0.7.12-1.tgz"}},"0.7.12-2":{"name...'
360 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I am using:-
node v12.18.3
npm  v6.14.6
MAC v10.14.6

I uninstalled node and reinstalled. Tried installing different versions of angular cli 10,9,8

Any help please.

Comment: Did you try removing `node_modules` and installing again?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to cache may got corrupted.

Try below command on command prompt. Recommended project directory.

```sh
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```